# How to regain use of Empathy?

Tags: 11.04, empathy, re-installation

So I don't actually know what happened, but I altered the .desktop file of Empathy (I added Skype as a quicklist shortcut) but for some reason, that removed Empathy from the Messaging Menu indicator. So I thought uninstalling and reinstalling Empathy might right everything that was wrong, but now when I try to install I get an error message that says:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

empathy: Depends: libcamel-1.2-23 (>= 3.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libcamel-1.2-23 (< 3.1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libgck0 (>= 2.91.1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libgcr-3-0 (>= 2.91.4) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libgnome-control-center1 (>= 1:2.91.2) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libnspr4 (>= 4.7.0~1.9b1) but 4.8.7-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: libnss3 (>= 3.12.2~rc1) but 3.12.9+ckbi-1.82-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
         Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.7.3) but 3.7.4-2ubuntu5 is to be installed
         Depends: libunity4 (>= 3.4.6) but 3.8.4-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: empathy-common (= 3.1.2.1-1ubuntu1~ppa11.04+1) but 3.1.2.1-1ubuntu1~ppa11.04+1 is to be installed
         Depends: gsettings-backend but it is a virtual package
```

Comment: Same problem. I tried upgrading empathy via the ppa's then I got this error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using Telepathy PPA, remove it and update your sources and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get -y --purge purge empathy && sudo apt-get -y install pidgin
```

JK. How do you replace empathy .desktop? Actually you need to place 'empathy' file in your ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications/ (create if not exists) with this content:

```
/usr/share/applications/empathy.desktop
```

This will adding empathy icon in messaging menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install empathy
```

If you didn't upgrade then update command maybe solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do the trick :(